# AngularJS socket.IO Bootstrap Modals only once

Tags: node.js, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, socket.io

I have a problem with bootstrap modal window when using AngularJS together with NodeJS and socket.io. I have been googling and it seems like it is issue that has a solution, but for some reason it doesn't work when I am trying to implement it together with Socket.io. I used modals on two different places - when I click on a static div (works perfectly), when I receive a message from webSockets (opens only once and then nothing). I guess I might have a problem in my JS code since the modal when I click on a static div works fine, but I don't know.

I have an address and I am sending some data via WebSockets to the client when this link is visited. The client event looks like this:

```
socket.on('patient', function(data){
    modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'templates/patient.js',
    controller: 'patientModalCtrl',
    resolve: {
      details: function(){return data;}
    }
  });
});
```

and:

```
socket.on('alergy',function(data){
  modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: "templates/alergy.js",
    controller: 'alergyModalCtrl'
  });
});
```

Both of these work only once and then the modal window stops to appear. Interesting is, that when I emit "alergy", then again and then "patient" I get an "alergy" window and then patient window the second "alergy" window under it.

emiting looks like this:

```
app.get('/api/socket/hash/:hash', function(req, res){ 
    var hash = req.params.hash;
    //allergy
    if(hash === "3fDecCD"){
        connected_sockets[0].emit('alergy', {alergy: true});
        res.json({status: true});
    }
    //patient detail
    else if(hash === "Vc43Sf"){
        connected_sockets[0].emit('patient', {name: 'Jan', surname: 'Bjornstad'});    
        res.json({status: true});
    }
    else{
        res.json({status: false});
    }
});
```

My template looks like this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header"></div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #FFD1D1;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: red;">Allergy!</h1>
        <h2 style="text-align: center; color: red;">The patient is allergic to opium!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using AngularJS 1.0.7, Bootstrap CSS 2.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that your socket-event listeners are firing "outside of AngularJS world" and as such AngularJS machinery is not kicking-in to do its 2-way data binding "magic". In precise terms, you are not entering AngularJS $digest loop so bindings are not updated, promises not resolved etc.

The easy fix is to wrap calls to AngularJS-specific code (here - call to the $modal service) into `Scope.$apply` method, ex.:

```
socket.on('alergy',function(data){

  $scope.$apply(function(){
    modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: "templates/alergy.js",
      controller: 'alergyModalCtrl'
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: You mister, you are a genius! It works perfectly. I read about $apply, but I probably have to read about it more, because i don't get it.

Comment: That did the trick for me too! I also will read up about $apply